# Resume Exoplayer Live Stream on Internet Connection Loss/Gain

Tags: java, android, rtmp, live-streaming, exoplayer

I am working on Exoplayer Media Player in Android to Live Stream from an RTMP Media Source URL. I am new to this kind a development so I am following the [official Tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0). The live stream is working fine on all Android Devices! My Class for fetching the live stream is:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.juni1289.exoplayertest2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.rtmp.RtmpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private ExoPlayer player;
    private boolean playWhenReady;
    private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter BANDWIDTH_METER = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    private ComponentListener componentListener;
    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private MediaSource videoSource;
    private AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory;
    private TrackSelector trackSelector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        componentListener = new ComponentListener();
        initializePlayer();
    }

    private void initializePlayer() {
        if (player == null) {
            // a factory to create an AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection
            adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);

            trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                    trackSelector,
                    new DefaultLoadControl());

            binding.videoView.setPlayer(player);


            RtmpDataSourceFactory rtmpDataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();

            // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
            videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(""),
                    rtmpDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

            playWhenReady = true;
            player.prepare(videoSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
            player.addListener(componentListener);
        }
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.removeListener(componentListener);
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideSystemUi();
        if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void hideSystemUi() {
        binding.videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }

    private class ComponentListener extends Player.DefaultEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {
            super.onTimelineChanged(timeline, manifest, reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            super.onTracksChanged(trackGroups, trackSelections);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
            super.onLoadingChanged(isLoading);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {
            super.onRepeatModeChanged(repeatMode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {
            super.onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(shuffleModeEnabled);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            super.onPlayerError(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
            super.onPositionDiscontinuity(reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
            super.onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekProcessed() {
            super.onSeekProcessed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
            super.onTimelineChanged(timeline, manifest);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            String stateString;
            switch (playbackState) {
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                    stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE      -";
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                    stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING -";
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                    stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_READY     -";
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                    stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED     -";
                    break;
                default:
                    stateString = "UNKNOWN_STATE             -";
                    break;
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "changed state to " + stateString
                    + " playWhenReady: " + playWhenReady);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The Gradle Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.7.3'
```

---

The URL is from **Nginx** Server implemented in the background, the backend live streaming software used is **Wirecast** using MacBook.

---

The problem I am facing is that when I have lost the Wifi connection (working),the Live stream won't resume at all. Similarly is with the 3G/4G Mobile Network Connection that once it goes down the live stream won't resume back.

I have followed the given tutorial and searched many of the forums for the problem resolution! But I am unable to find any resource information in order to rectify the problem!

---

I purposed a solution for me that a Broadcast receiver is registered in the MainActivity that will check of Internet Connections, once it changes it state the Exoplayer will be re-initialized. But this has limitation, that it only works when the Wifi or the Mobile Data Connection will turn on or off!

I want Exoplayer to resume the live stream when Wifi or Mobile Data Connection goes down and then it got some life and the Exoplayer resume the live stream to be watch again!

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated! As I am new to this development, any blunders can occur in my code.

---

I am also trying with the following code too:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Format;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.decoder.DecoderCounters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.rtmp.RtmpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultAllocator;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoRendererEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoRendererEventListener {

    private SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
    private final String logKEY = "MainActivity";
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private MediaSource videoSource;
    private final String url = "myurl";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
        initExoPlayer();
    }

    private void initExoPlayer() {
        try {
            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory videoSelectionFactory=new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

            //TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoSelectionFactory);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Create the player

            DefaultAllocator defaultAllocator = new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

            DefaultLoadControl defaultLoadControl = new DefaultLoadControl(defaultAllocator, 30,
                    30, 10, DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS,
                    DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_TARGET_BUFFER_BYTES, DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_PRIORITIZE_TIME_OVER_SIZE_THRESHOLDS);
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, defaultLoadControl);
            exoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
            exoPlayerView.setUseController(false);


            RtmpDataSourceFactory rtmpDataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();

            // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
            videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(url),
                    rtmpDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);


            // Prepare the player with the source.
            player.prepare(videoSource);
            //auto start playing
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            //adding listeners
            player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                    if (isLoading) {
                        Log.e(logKEY, "loadingChanged:::true");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(logKEY, "loadingChanged:::false");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                    Log.e(logKEY, "Listener-onPlayerError...");
                    player.stop();
                    player.prepare(videoSource);
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekProcessed() {

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(logKEY, "error:::" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        exoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.exoPlayerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDroppedFrames(int count, long elapsedMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
        Log.e(logKEY, "onVideoSizeChanged [" + " width: " + width + " height: " + height + "]");
        Log.e(logKEY, "RES:(WxH):" + width + "X" + height + "\n           " + height + "p");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderedFirstFrame(Surface surface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(logKEY, "onStop()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(logKEY, "onStart()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(logKEY, "onResume()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(logKEY, "onPause()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(logKEY, "onDestroy()...");
        player.release();
    }
}
```

---

The above is also having the said issues!

Comment: I also want to resume streaming after server down and again wake up . have anybody solve this ??